# search for keyword in extracted text javascript

Tags: javascript

So I managed to extract some text, and then I saved it as a variable for later use, how can I test for certain keywords within said text?

Here's an example, `checkTitle` is the text I extracted, and I want to search it for certain keywords, in this example, the words delimited by commas within `compareTitle`. I want to search for the strings `'5'` and  `'monkeys'`.

```
var checkTitle = "5 monkeys jumping on the bed";
var compareTitle = "5 , monkeys";

if (checkTitle === compareTitle) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to search for strings, and the [`test()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) function to return true/false if the string contains the words.

```
/(?:^|\s)(?:(?:monkeys)|(?:5))\s+/gi.test("5 monkeys jumping on the bed");
```

will return true, because the string contains either (in this case, both) the words 5 and monkeys.

See my example here: http://regexr.com/39ti7 to use the site's tools to analyse each aspect of the regular expression.

If you need to change the words you are testing for each time, then you can use this code:

```
function checkForMatches(){
  var words = checkTitle.split(" , ");
  var patt;
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    patt = patt + "(" + words[i] + ")|";
  }
  patt[patt.length-1] = "";
  patt = new RegExp(patt, "i");
  return patt.test(checkTitle);
}
```

will return true, and allow for any words you want to be checked against. They must be separated like this:

```
compareText = "word1 , word2 , word3 , so on , ...";
//                  ^^^notice, space-comma-space.
```

And you can use it in an if statement like this:

```
var checkTitle = "5 monkeys jumping on the bed";
var compareTitle = "5 , monkeys";
if (checkForMatches()){
  //a match was found!
}
```

Comment: I have a question can i use the the .contains() method instead for looking for the strings in the text i extracted, and i can add the keywords in an array?

Comment: Yes. I will create a new answer for this new(ish) question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`String.prototype.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) method you can search for substrings within strings. For example,

```
"Hi there everyone!".contains("Hi");        //true
"Hi there everyone!".contains("there e");   //true
"Hi there everyone!".contains("goodbye");   //false
```

You can also use [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to a similar effect:

```
("Hi there everyone!".indexOf("Hi") > -1)   //true
("Hi there everyone!".indexOf("Hmmn") > -1) //false
```

However, in this method, we don't even need to use any of the above methods, as the `.match()` method will do it all for us:

To return an array of the matched keywords, use [`.match()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp). It accepts a regular expression as an argument, and returns an array of substrings which match the regular expression.

```
var checkTitle = "5 monkeys jumping on the bed";
var compareTitle = "5 , monkeys";
/*                   ^^^
  It is very important to separate each word with space-comma-space */

function getWords(str){ //returns an array containing key words
  return str.split(" , ");
}

function matches(str, words){
  var patt = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    patt =  (i > 0)? patt + "|" + "(" + words[i] + ")" : patt + "(" + words[i] + ")";
  }
  patt[patt.length-1] = "";
  patt = new RegExp(patt, 'gi');
  //                        ^ i makes it case-insensitive
  return str.match(patt);
}

matches(compareTitle, getWords(checkTitle)); // should return ['5','monkeys']
```

you can check if a match exists by doing this:

```
if (matches(compareTitle, getWords(checkTitle))){
  // matches found
}
```

If this answer is better than the first, accept this one instead. Ask for any more help, or if it doesn't work.